# first-fit, best-fit e worst-fit python

Tags: python, gerenciamento-de-memória

Eu  tenho que fazer um *software* que implemente os algoritmos de gerenciamento de memória `first-fit`, `best-fit` e `worst-fit`, eu sei o conceito deles, o `first-fit` coloca o dado no primeiro espaço que caiba, `best-fit` lê todos e seleciona o menor espaço que caiba e o `worst-fit` le todos e seleciona o maior espaço que caiba, aqui está meu codigo:

```
import random

memoria = [' '] * 100
opcao = 0
tamanho = 0
letra = ''
for i in range(100):
    if(random.randint(0,11) >= 5):
        memoria[i] = 'x'
    else:
        memoria[i] = ' '

while(opcao != 4):
    #Menu do programa
    print("1 - Primeira Escolha")
    print("2 - Melhor Escolha")
    print("3 - Pior Escolha")
    print("4 - Sair")
    print("Escolha o algoritmo pelo numero")
    opcao = int(input())
    print("Digite o tamanho da informacao")
    tamanho = int(input())
    print("Digite a letra a ser utiliada")
    letra = input()

    if(opcao == 1):
    #Implemente aqui a lógica da primeira escolha
        pass
    else:
        if (opcao == 2):
            #Implemente aqui a lógica da melhor escolha
            pass
        else:
            if(opcao == 3):
                #Implemente aqui a lógica da pior escolha
                pass
# Aqui você deve imprimir todo o conteúdo da variável memória
```

A minha duvida é assim: digamos que a memoria seja essa:

```
x| |x| |x|x|x|x| | |x| |x|x| | | |x| | |
x|x|x|x| |x| |x| | |x|x| |x|x| |x|x| |x|
 |x|x|x| |x| | | |x|x| |x|x| | |x|x| |x|
x|x|x|x|x| |x|x|x|x| | | |x| |x|x|x| |x|
 | | |x| | |x|x|x| | |x|x| |x|x|x| | | |
```

O tamanho da informação seja 2 e a letra a ser utilizada seja O, digamos que seja utilizado a opção 1, a memoria deveria ficar assim:

```
x| |x| |x|x|x|x|O|O|x| |x|x| | | |x| | |
x|x|x|x| |x| |x| | |x|x| |x|x| |x|x| |x|
 |x|x|x| |x| | | |x|x| |x|x| | |x|x| |x|
x|x|x|x|x| |x|x|x|x| | | |x| |x|x|x| |x|
 | | |x| | |x|x|x| | |x|x| |x|x|x| | | |
```

Para achar um espaço que não tenha nada eu poderia utilizar

```
if memoria[i] == ' ':
```

dessa forma eu conseguiria achar a posição no vetor que estão vazia, mas como o tamanho da informação é 2 (hipoteticamente):

Como eu pego 2 posições ao mesmo tempo para mudar?

Se alguém puder tirar essa dúvida pra mim eu ficaria muito agradecido e desculpa se essa duvida for meio *noob* pois estou aprendendo a pouco tempo programação.

Comment: Você pode armazenar em uma variável temporária as posições que achou livre. Depois, volte nelas e faça a alocação da memória.

Answer (score 1):

Expandindo a ideia do Leonardo:

Salve a posição do espaço livre que você está considerando. Por exemplo, seu primeiro espaço livre está na posição 1. Aí você tem duas variáveis-- digamos, `posicaoEmConsideracao` e `qtdDeEspacosVazios`. A primeira você vai inicializar com essa posição - 1 (porque começa em 0). A segunda você inicializa como 1, porque você só achou um espaço vazio até o momento.

Se a próxima posição for um espaço, incremente `qtdDeEspacosVazios`. Se estiver ocupada, invalide `posicaoEmConsideracao` e comece de novo.

No momento que `qtdDeEspacosVazios` for igual a `tamanho`, preencha de `posicaoEmConsideracao` até `posicaoEmConsideracao + tamanho` com `x`. Você pode fazer isso com um `while`, que você já conhece.

Claro que em cada caso você tem uma gerência diferente a fazer. Isso aí é só pro *first-fit*. Mas é só uma questão de salvar posições em variáveis, mudando a estratégia em cada caso.

Ah, e você também poderia estar usando uma [lista encadeada](https://pt.wikibooks.org/wiki/Sistemas_operacionais/Sistemas_de_arquivos#Lista_Encadeada) para gerenciar a memória. Facilitaria bastante a busca dos espaços vazios.